# Detect component content change in Ractive.js

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

Is there any way of detecting when the content of a component changes?

For example:

HTML:

```
<component>
    <div>{{name}}</div>
</component>
```

JS:

```
component = Ractive.extend({
    on...: function () {
        // invoked when the inner HTML changes
    }
});
```

I use `{{yield}}` so the content is rendered in the context of the parent.

For now I'll have to pass `name` to the component just for the purpose of observing changes (even though I don't need the value in the context of the component). (Or I'll add a function that I can call).

```
<component changes="{{name}}">
    <div>{{name}}</div>
</component>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but a bit hacky.

http://plnkr.co/edit/YoTZpyTTyCyXijEteGkg?p=preview

```
    <comp>
        {{name}} hi {{thing}}
    </comp>
```

```
    comp = Ractive.extend({
        template: '<div>{{yield}}</div>',
        oncomplete: function() {

            var self = this;

            self.partials.content.forEach(function(partial) {

                if (partial.r) {
                    self.parent.observe(partial.r, function(newValue) {
                        console.log(partial.r + ' changed to ', newValue)
                    }, {init: false});
                }

            });
        }
    })
```

Yield/Content are really just special partials, so this will loop through the items in that partial and set up an observer for each keypath.

This demo only works with simple expressions like `{{foo}}`. If you have more complicated things inside the partial you'll have to inspect the rendered partial to figure out what keypath you want to observe the parent on.